# Activation of conditional blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created this code but an error (*la compilation conditionnelle est désactivée*) so what is the matter and how can I correct it

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication7.Models.GoogleMarker>
@using System.Threading;
@using System.Globalization;
@{

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lay2.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var options = {
        zoom : 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var googleMap = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0],options);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "Cargando…" });
    @foreach (var marker in Model){
    <text>
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(@marker.Latitude, @marker.Longitude);
        bounds.extend(point);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point,map: googleMap,icon:'/Content/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png.png',html: '@marker.InfoWindow'});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {infoWindow.setContent(this.html);infoWindow.open(googleMap, this);});
    </text>
    }
    googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);}
    );
     </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google translation (for non-French speakers like me): "conditional compilation is turned off". (Would not the solution be to turn _on_ conditional compilation?)

Comment: Did you try adding `/*@cc_on @*/` to your code?

Comment: where can i add /*@cc_on @*/ in my code explain please

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y5529x3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), "Add the following statement to the beginning of your conditional code: /*@cc_on @*/".